# How to reuse results with a schema for end of day stock-data

Tags: sql, schema, finance, stocks

I am creating a database schema to be used for technical analysis like top-volume gainers, top-price gainers etc.I have checked answers to questions here, like  [the design question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523576/database-schema-for-organizing-historical-stock-data). Having taken the hint from *boe100* 's answer there I have a schema modeled pretty much on it, thusly:

```
Symbol -  char 6               //primary
Date -  date                   //primary 
Open -  decimal 18, 4
High -  decimal 18, 4
Low -  decimal 18, 4
Close -  decimal 18, 4
Volume -  int
```

Right now this table containing End Of Day( EOD) data will be about 3 million rows for 3 years. Later when I get/need more data it could be 20  million rows.

The front end will be asking requests like "give me the top price gainers on date X over Y days". That request is one of the simpler ones, and as such is not too costly, time wise, I assume.

But a request like " give me top volume gainers for the last 10 days, with the previous 100 days acting as baseline", could prove 10-100 times costlier. The result of such a request would be a float which signifies how many times the volume as grown etc.

One option I have is adding a column for each such result. And if the user asks for volume gain in 10 days over 20 days, that would require another column. The total such columns could easily cross 100, specially if I start adding other results as columns, like MACD-10, MACD-100. each of which will require its own column.

Is this a feasible solution?

Another option being that I keep the result in cached html files and present them to the user. I dont have much experience in web-development, so to me it looks messy; but I could be wrong ( ofc!) . Is that a option too?

Let me add that I am/will be using mod_perl to present the response to the user. With much of the work on mysql database being done using perl. I would like to have a response time of 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You should **keep your data normalised** as much as possible, and let the RDBMS do its work: efficiently performing queries based on the normalised data.

Don't second-guess what will or will not be efficient; instead, **only optimise in response to specific, measured inefficiencies** as reported by the RDBMS's query explainer.

Valid tools for optimisation include, in rough order of preference:

- **Normalising the data further**, to allow the RDBMS to decide for itself how best to answer the query.
- **Refactoring the specific query** to remove the inefficiencies reported by the query explainer. This will give good feedback on how the application might be made more efficient, or might lead to a better normalisation of relations as above.
- **Creating indexes** on attributes that turn out, in practice, to be used in a great many transactions. This can be quite effective, but it is a trade-off of slowdown on most write operations as indexes are maintained, to gain speed in some specific read operations when the indexes are used.
- Creating supplementary **tables to hold intermediary pre-computed results** for use in future queries. This is rarely a good idea, not least because it totally breaks the DRY principle; you now have to come up with a strategy of keeping duplicate information (the original data and the derived data) in sync, when the RDBMS will do its job best when there is *no* duplicated data.

None of those involve messing around inside the tables that store the primary data.