# Numeric vs Real Datypes for Storing Monetary Values

Tags: postgresql, types

An answer to [a question about a good schema for stock data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523576/database-schema-for-organizing-historical-stock-data) recommended this schema:

```
 Symbol -  char 6
 Date -  date
 Time -  time
 Open -  decimal 18, 4
 High -  decimal 18, 4
 Low -  decimal 18, 4
 Close -  decimal 18, 4
 Volume -  int
```

In addition, Postgres documentation says:

"If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead (of floating point types)."

I'm fairly new at SQL, and I hope this is not a really naive question.  I'm wondering about the necessity of using the numeric datatype (especially 18,4) - it seems like overkill to me.  And "exact" is not really something I'd specify, if exact means correct out to 12 decimal places.

I'm thinking of using real 10,2 for the monetary columns.  Here's my rationale.

A typical calculation might compare a stock price (2 decimal places) to a moving average (that could have many decimal places), to determine which is larger.  My understanding is that the *displayed* value of the average (and any calculated results) would be rounded to 2 decimal places, but that calculations would be performed using the higher precision of the stored internal number.

So such a calculation would be accurate to at least 2 decimal places, which is really all I need, I think.

Am I way off base here, and is it possible to get an incorrect answer to the above comparison by using the  real 10,2 datatype?

I'd also welcome any other comments, pro or con, about using the numeric datatype.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1):

Floating point variables are vulnerable to floating point errors. Therefore, if accuracy is important (anytime money is involved) it's always recommended to use a numeric type.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems

[Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the schema above, and look how 18,4 would look like in floating point numbers:

```
select '12345678901234.5678'::float4;
  float4    
-------------
 1.23457e+13
(1 row)

select '12345678901234.5678'::double precision;
  float8      
------------------
 12345678901234.6
(1 row)
```

Therefore 14 numbers (before the decimal point) will always round your number, and you store rounded (and therefore wrong) values.

Also your assumption about rounding to two decimal places - where is that assumption coming from?

```
select '1.2345678'::float4;
 float4  
---------
 1.23457
(1 row)
```

Therefore, so far you presented a number of assumptions, and shortcuts, without showing why you want to use floating point numbers instead of numeric. What is your compelling reason? Just save some bytes?

My next question is: if your application expands, and does more than just "avg" calculations - do you need to chance the data type to numeric again?