# Implement database schema for organizing historical stock data

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, stock

I am new to MySQL, I try to use MySQL to store my stock data.

I followed the answer by `boe100` in reference:

- [Database schema for organizing historical stock data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523576/database-schema-for-organizing-historical-stock-data#)

I create my table as follows:

mysql> describe StockDailyQuotations;

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ts_code | varchar(9) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| trade_date | int(8) | NO | PRI | NULL |  |
| open | decimal(6,2) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| high | decimal(6,2) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| low | decimal(6,2) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| close | decimal(6,2) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| change | decimal(6,2) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| pct_chg | float | YES |  | NULL |  |
| vol | float | YES |  | NULL |  |
| amount | float | YES |  | NULL |  |

`10 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

I always use the table in two following ways:

(1) search one stock's history data, It takes 0.01 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM StockDailyQuotations WHERE ts_code='000001.SZ';
```

(2) search all stock's data in one day. It takes 1.94 seconds.

```
SELECT * FROM StockDailyQuotations WHERE trade_date='20201231';
```

The answer in reference said: "We also have a clustered index on symbol, date and time columns.
We can get data out of the server in a matter of milliseconds. Remember, the database size is almost 1 terabyte." But in my case, searching 1 is fast enough,  I want to accelerate type 2 searching.

I think the primary key on ts_code and trade_date is already made the clustered index.
Do I misunderstand anything? How can I accelerate the searching (2)?

I apologize if it is a stupid problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is `amount`?

Comment: And vol is the amount of stock?

Comment: Sorry, `amount` is `Stock turnover` and `vol` is `Stock trading volume`. One counts the sum of the price, and one is counting the sum of trading.

Comment: Sir, do you suggest using int to store the `amount` and `vol`?

Comment: `FLOAT` is fine if its limitation of about 7 _siginificant_ digits is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It's not a "stupid problem", just a "novice question".)

```
PRIMARY KEY(ts_code, trade_date)
INDEX(trade_date)
```

But have `trade_date DATE` (not `INT`)

`DECIMAL(6,2)` limits you to 9999.99; is that OK?

Use `ENGINE=InnoDB`

Be cautious of other Questions that are not tagged [mysql] or [mariadb]; they are likely to have syntax and other suggestions that are not good for MySQL.

If you include "time", it is probably better to use a single `DATETIME` column, not two columns (`DATE` and `TIME`).  However, this leads to some tricky business when requesting info for a given date.

Comment: Sir, my date only contains the year, month, day, such as `20211001` means `Oct-01-2020`. Is int good enough for it?

Comment: Don't try to add "one day" to such an INT.  With a DATE, you can do `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Answer (score 1):

I create an index for 'trade_date', searching way (2) can have same performance with way (1).